# Android Studio says "Cause: not a valid name: class"

Tags: java, android

When trying to build my Android app, I get an error that says `"Cause: not a valid name: class"`. It doesn't give me any other information at all.

Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/4guRqdLu

Comment: It's likely to give you a bit more information. Share your stacktrace. Check your Java compilation options, Kotlin compilation options and which JVM you are using.

Comment: did you try to name a class or variable `class`?

Comment: @LukeDuncan Where would I find the stacktrace? It shows the build view with the Build Output tab and all that it says is "Cause: not a valid name: class"

Comment: @TylerV I am not finding anything that is named class that shouldn't be

Comment: @ndsmith try running `./gradlew assemble --debug` from your terminal.

Comment: @LukeDuncan added the stacktrace

Comment: Check your XML files. Looks like you have the Android XML namespace twice in one of them, probably a layout file.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,327]
    Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout&layout_width&http://sch
    emas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

Comment: Looks like it's from the XML. Look at the bottom. `Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,327]
    Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout&layout_width`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a different word than 'class' mine was '1kg'. The problem was that I used '_1kg' as an id in XML so make sure you didn't use 'class' in your XML at all. (as id or even for extract string resource)

Answer (score 0):

this error happened to me, and I solved it in an easy way.

In one XML file, I set an id in the Kiril alphabet like кр

after changing this ID, this problem was solved.
So check your XML file and ids and ensure every ID and name is in the Latin alphabet.